# Is it possible to change the Invite/Welcome e-mail for a site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, email

We are using SharePoint Online, and when we invite members to a new site, they will receive an e-mail like this:

> Here's the site that Administrator shared with you.
>
> Go to **Sharepoint Site**
>
> **Follow** this site to get updates in your newsfeed.

I just want to remove the "Go to SharePoint" site part. Is it possible to customise that OOTB e-mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not possible. The ”Go to SharePoint Site” link uses a one-time URL making the user chose sign in option. Either by an organizational Office 365 account or by a Live-ID account (if it’s external users). This has yet to be resolved/developed by Microsoft. But it’s requested, and may happen in the near future.

Reference: [How to send invite email to an external user with custom message?](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/235541.aspx)